# How to get multiple images data in laravel controller(API) from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

My form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="createProduct">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input required name="name" type="text">
<textarea name="description"></textarea>
<input id="imageToUpload" type="file"name="images[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

My Script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$('#createProduct').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault(e);
var redirect_url = "{{ route('products.list') }}";
var url = "{{ route('products.store') }}";
var method = $(this).attr('method');
var formData = new FormData;
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  formData.append(images[i].name, images[i])
}
var myData = {
  name: $(this).find("[name='name']").val(),
  description: $(this).find("[name='description']").val(),
  images: formData
}
$.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: url,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: myData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    window.location.href = redirect_url;
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
      console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
  }
});
});
```

My Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
$input = Input::all();
return Response::json([
     'message' => 'Product Created Succesfully',
     'data' => $input 
], 200);
```

How to send data(with images) from form to ajax

How to retrieve data(with images) from ajax to store(API) function in the controller.

so that i can process and save the files.

Comment: have u tried `images: $(this).find('#imageToUpload').val()` instead of `images: formData`

Answer (score 0):

You store the images as a base64 encoded string and pass that to the server, that will then convert it back as an image.

To do so listen for a change on the image input, and convert the image to base 64 with a FileReader:

```
$("#imageToUpload").change(function() {
 var file = $(this).prop("files")[0];
    if (file != undefined) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("loadstart", function() {
            // You can do something to tell the user the conversion started
        });

        // Store the file as a base64 string
        reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
            myData.image = reader.result;
            // Get the name of the file, removing the path
            myData.imageName = $(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
        });

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

And then read it in the controller and store it with file_put_contents():

```
// Get rid of the base64 header to parse the image
list($type, $input->image) = explode(';', $input->image);
list(, $input->image)      = explode(',', $input->image);
// Store the image
file_put_contents("/your/path" . $input->imageName, base64_decode($input->image));
```

I doubt this code is completely accurade, but should be a good starting point.

Comment: is there a way to append multiple images array to formdata and pass to the controller ?

Comment: Sure, as you can see `$(this).prop("files")`  returns an array with all the files in the input. So you could simple iterate over it and store each file.